# iOS7 baseSDK running on iOS8 can't select UISearchBar

Tags: ios, ios8, uisearchbar

I'm doing everything programmatically just to make things easier to understand, but I still can't find the issue.

First I present a new NavigationController with a root UIViewController:

```
  - (IBAction)searchButonPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
CTVNewSearchTableViewController *searchVC = [[CTVNewSearchTableViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:searchVC];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{
}];
}
```

On ViewDidLoad of CTVNewSearchTableViewController I call a function to create a UIsearchBar:

```
- (void)createSearchBar {
        UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
        self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
        self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
        searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 38);
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
}
```

In Xcode 5 If I run this on the iOS7 simulator it works fine. Also if I open Xcode 6 and run the same code with a base SDK of iOS8 it also works fine. However if I run it on my iOS8 iPhone I cannot select the search bar. Is there anything I can do to get it to run correctly without building in Xcode 6?